# Fading in/out a UILabel

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uiviewanimation

My stackview contains 2 labels. I want to animate the hiding process like giving it a fade out animation when one of the labels is hidden or a fade in animation when one of the labels is unhidden. How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should animate the `alpha` of the `label`.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
    disclaimerLabel.alpha = 0
}
```

Comment: but my label is not in an UIView. And I tried adding a view but when I tried to add .animate it said "Static member 'animate' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIView'"

Comment: `disclaimerView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            disclaimerLabel.alpha = 0 //0 to fade out. 1 to fade in
        }`

Comment: you should not substitute `UIView` with `disclaimerView`. it is a class func of `UIView`. Check my edited answer

Answer (score -1):

```
    let flash = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "opacity")
    flash.duration = 0.5
    flash.fromValue = 1
    flash.toValue = 0.1
    flash.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    flash.autoreverses = true
    flash.repeatCount = 3

    la1.layer.add(flash, forKey: nil)
```